# More issues with TypeScript modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, package.json

... yep. It's that time of year again. TypeScript is wonderful, except for the mess that is the module system. Presently, I'm struggling with a scenario where I'm dealing with two separate repositories / projects (what ever you wanna call it). I've got a library and a program using said library. I'm using Node's [subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) feature in the `package.json` to indicate multiple submodules within the library. From the NodeJS (and the bundler's perspective) this is fine, but not in TypeScript's world. TypeScript is adamant that none of the modules exist.

### [Here's a quick summary of the library](https://github.com/J-Cake/jcake-utils)

`/utils`

- `package.json`
- `tsconfig.json`
- `build` *automatically generated build directory*

  - `iter.js`
  - `iterSync.js`
  - ...
  - `lib` *autogenerated declarations files*

    - `iter.d.ts`
    - `iterSync.d.ts`
    - ...
- `src` *source files*

  - `iter.ts`
  - `iter_sync.ts`
  - ...
- `lib` *manually written definitions files*

  - `iter.d.ts`
  - `iterSync.d.ts`

It's [`package.json`](https://github.com/J-Cake/jcake-utils/tree/main/package.json) has an `exports` field which defines a list of exports and their respective declaration file.

#### `library/package.json`

```json
...
"exports": {
  "./iter": "build/iter.js",
  "./iterSync": "build/iterSync.js",
  ...
}
...
```

I've tried various alterations of the above, such as

- [`Node16` module resolution strategy](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079#issuecomment-1128910470)
- [Adding a `types` property to each export](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079#issuecomment-1129096299)
- Using the `main` and `typings` fields in `library/package.json`
- Adding `"lib"` to the `includes` of `library/tsconfig.json`
- Upgrading to TypeScript 4.6.4
- Restarting the TS Language Server through the VSCode command menu
- Basically all permutations of the above

### How I use the library

I don't think it makes a difference, but I'm referencing the module through a pnpm `link` dependency statement for development, and a `git://...` url for production:

#### `program/package.json`

```json
...
"dependencies": {
  "jcake-utils": "link:../library", // dev
  "jcake-utils": "github:J-Cake/jcake-utils", // prod
  ...
}
```

Regardless of what I do, TypeScript refuses to locate my submodules in the program

```js
...
import Iter, * as iter from 'jcake-utils/iter';
import IterSync, * as iterSync from 'jcake-utils/iterSync';
...
```

```sh
$ pnpm exec tsc -v
Version 4.6.4
$ pnpm exec tsc -p program/tsconfig.json
src/build.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jcake-utils/iter' or its corresponding type declarations.

... (A bajillion errors saying exactly the same thing, just across different files)
```

I alluded to this being a common issue (because from my experience it is) but I would greatly appreciate some very specific feedback as to how I can correct this issue and/or if I should potentially restructure either program or library, and how best to do so. I've been unable to find documentation that is helpful in my situation, as many of the suggestions given by the TypeScript community have not worked.

Thanks kindly

Comment: Same problem, it's probably not supported. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

Comment: Wow that is seriously frustrating. I do sincerely wish there were some consistency across all these different module systems

Comment: Here is a solution, but I can't get it working
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#package-json-exports-imports-and-self-referencing

Comment: I ended up getting it working by bombing my whole project and making giving each submodule it's own `package.json`. Not pretty, but it works
Thanks for all your efforts though. If I could give you rep, I would